Is facial mocap possible in Blender?
I'm attempting facial mocap using a custom-recorded FBX export with a model that has 52 pre-made shape keys:
The results are less than desirable:

It also appears the meshes' shape key are not compatible compatible with Blender's Rigify or FaceIt. I assumed these shape keys were universal.
I have a few questions:
-Is it possible to record facial mocap in Blender directly?
-Is retargeting the face possible in Blender?
Or am I going about this the wrong way? Any advice or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Sorry but this Q&A site is here to help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons only. Problems using external applications and third-party addons are off-topic here and many people will have never heard of the meshes and 'FaceCap' that you are talking about.

Thanks for the heads up John, I will rephrase my question, as these base meshes have shape keys built specifically for Blender. Rigify and FaceIt are Blender add-ons.

Rigify is a built-in Blender addon, but Faceit is a third-party one so you'll have to ask the developers about that one.

No problem, will do. Thank you @JohnEason

Theoretically, motion capture recording is possible within Blender, and I have done it, but most motion capture recording apps I’ve seen are written standalone with file export, and maybe a blender addon for import, rather than with or as a blender addon for directly recording motion capture information into Blender. Finding such software is beyond the scope of this site.
As for retargeting, yes, it can be done, and Thankfully fairly simply if I recall. I am unfamiliar with the subject at current, but I researched it bit when I was messing with motion capture awhile ago, and there are several different ways to do it, including a packed-in addon to help with common use cases. You should look up “blender retargeting” to find out more.

I'd recommend Google's Mediapipe Face Landmarker, if you are fluent in Python. It provides values for how much certain facial components move, such as how open the mouth is, and how raised the eyebrows are.
There are many addons on Github that use Mediapipe to map facial motions onto rigs-mainly the Rigify rig, such as BlendAR Mocap or VIPER Blender Facial Motion Capture. I'd look into some of these. They both map facial motions onto the rig in real time.
As for your issue with the shape keys, it appears that your shape keys may be interfering with one another, since multiple are changing at the same time in response to the same movements in the face. You may need to reduce the number of shape keys you have, or entirely rely on the Rigify rig.

Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules links to answers are not answers if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.
